USB-C to 3.5 mm audio jack using MAX20328
I'm trying to build a USB-C to 3.5 mm audio jack adapter using a MAX20328.
This is my schematic:

What else do I need and/or have missed? I just want basic functionality so I can connect a headset with a 3.5 mm audio plug to the USB-C port of my phone. What are DM_AP1/DP_AP1 and DM_AP2/DP_AP2 used for? On the evaluation board it looks like they are connected to two female USB-A ports.

This is not a chip for beginners (if you are not, forgive me); it requires configuration over I2C, which is not connected on your schematic, USB layout is not trivial, and the entire package can fit between two adjacent pins of a DIP package. Furthermore, it does not appear to be designed to drive any sort of headphone or speaker directly.

AP1/AP2 means audio path 1 and 2, typically used for daisy chaining multiple speakers and/or microphones. If your application is simply a USB-C to single audio jack, i.e. only mono or stereo sound systems, I don't think you'd have to worry about that.

Thanks, do I need to configure the ic over i2c everytimes it boots or can I do it once?

if even if you get the design right, you have essentially no hope of assembling this without specialist equipment - the package is insanely small (5x5 array on 0.4mm pitch, the whole chip is just over 2mm square).

Yeay I do understand its tiny :) anyway it seems you have to write the MODE bits and the EN bit over i2c to enable the ic and thus not what I wanted. Can any one suggest another ic that is suitable. I want as few extra components as possible, such as external clocks for example. And preferable with a small footprint.

Analog Devices already offers an assembled and tested evaluation kit board for this product, start there instead of trying to build your own from scratch. Especially with such small package size. But read the documentation first; it's not clear to me whether a fault-protected multiplexer is really what you want here. Your question makes it seem like you actually want some kind of USB-C to 3.5mm audio adapter, something like an audio CODEC not a MUX.

Here's the Analog Devices product selector table for audio codec (coder-decoder or adc-dac) parts: https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/13041#/

Yes @MarkU you are correct, its not a mux I want. Im changing my design to another ic.
